Is there any difference between 'should' and 'be advisable that'?
Both words imply that somebody should do something. Is there any difference between them? For example:

People should stick to their boring jobs until they have overcome their most urgent financial issues.
It is advisable that people stick to their boring jobs until they have overcome their most urgent financial issues.

P.S. The above example is in answer to whether people should be unemployed or stay in a job they hate.

It is advisable is formal. Therefore, remain in jobs that are not ideal. For example.

I voted to close because "any difference" is far too broad a question. Please clarify.  They are not interchangeable  in many situations.  "A: It is advisable to give her a call. B: -- Why should I call her?   A: I just feel it's the right thing to do."

There's a fair amount of difference. Please edit to show that you've looked up "should" and "advisable" (or you might even get better results with "advise") and what you found. I think the question that comes from those edits will be more answerable.

I'll go ahead and hint: "advice" is inherently pragmatic, logical, reasonable. We can force a difference by imagining a "should" that comes from other reasons, like heroic sacrifice or an ethical code.

I'll start by saying that the choice is not simply about being "polite". There is nothing inherently impolite about saying one should do something. True, some don't like to be told what they "should" do, but that is subjective - many people accept that they should follow instructions from authority figures such as teachers, employers etc. There are also times when a 'clear steer' - being told what we should do - is exactly what we want.
When speaking, we consider our audience. If a person has the authority to say what one "should" do, then you might well phrase an advisory that way. But, if we really want the person to act on the advice then we have to consider what words would be the most motivating. Saying that something is "advisable" often has that motivating effect. Firstly, because it is impersonal. It sounds like this is the advice of others, not necessarily yourself. It implies that most people would follow the advice. Secondly, it encourages autonomy. Many are more likely to do something if they conclude that it is best for themselves than if they are told it is what they 'should' do.

What you say about authority figures is true, of course - I was thinking of a private individual declaring what people 'should' do.

Saying that people in general  should do something comes across as rather arrogant. It's what you think they ought to do, but it's not your job to tell them how to organise their lives.
Saying that a certain course of action is advisable is more polite - it implies "If they asked me, that is what I would advise them to do".

The two examples have similar meanings.
For information, they have different sentence structures.   (2) has an extraposition.
The version without extraposition is
[That people stick to their boring jobs until they have overcome their most urgent financial issues] is advisable.
